# "This file came from another computer..." - how can I unblock all the files in a folder without having to unblock them individually?

Tags: windows, security, ntfs

Windows XP SP2 and Windows Vista have this deal where zone information is preserved in downloaded files to NTFS partitions, such that it blocks certain files in certain applications until you "unblock" the files.

So for example if you download a zip file of source code to try something out, every file will display this in the security settings of the file properties

> "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer"

Along with an "Unblock" button. Some programs don't care, but Visual Studio will refuse to load projects in solutions until they've been unblocked.

While it's not terribly difficult to go to every project file and unblock it individually, it's a pain. And it does not appear you can unblock multiple selected files simultaneously.

Is there any way to unblock all files in a directory without having to go to them all individually?

**I know you can turn this off globally for all new files but let's say I don't want to do that**

Comment: How does one turn this off globally? Link please? :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, worst Windows "feature" ever...

Comment: Second worst. The first worst is auto-run on newfound media, which is what started this mess.

Comment: @Thomas As one of the answers points out, you can do this by setting the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments\SaveZoneInformation = 1. More info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260

Comment: @jamiebarrow: I cant the key on Windows 8.1. Any alternate solution for globally turning off the thing?

Comment: Schnapple - Perhaps this question should be tagged with [tag:Internet-Explorer], as up until recently (as far as I am aware) this is the only browser that tags it's downloaded files in this manner. ALL - On the page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260 that [jamiebarrow](http://superuser.com/users/69108) provided [above](http://superuser.com/questions/38476/#comment643530_38476), the relevant section is titled "Do not preserve zone information in file attachments" (Annoying that MS doesn't use uniquely ID'd elements, to make # referencing easier).
@tumchaaditya..Try creating all missing keys

Comment: My downloads in Google Chrome get tagged and I have to unblock them.  @jamiebarrow has the right information for disabling this globally via the registry, or you can use the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) and change the setting in User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Attachment Manager > Do not preserve zone information in file attachments > Enabled.

Comment: The solution is obtaining a EV (extra validation) Code Signing Certificate and signing your executable. For example: https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-code-signing.htm

Comment: Third worst windows feature. The worst is focus grabbing by applications, taking the input you intended for another program and acting upon it before you know.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If you download a `.ZIP` and unzip it, the individual files will be marked as the same zone as the `.ZIP`.  Almost every time I have a folder full of "blocked" files, this is how I got them.

Before unzipping, click the Unblock button on the `.ZIP`.

Comment: This one's definitely the easiest - you win

Comment: +1 same conclusion I came to - an easy way to package files in a non-NTFS manner - found this by searching Google for these terms: unblock all files in a directory xp.

Comment: Actually, no. I download zip-files to use the content and I let my browser open the zip file automatically. From there I invoke "Extract all files". There is no option to unblock from these location, and hunting down the zip file in the download folder or even worse, the temp folder, is *very* tedious.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Comment: This solution only works if you haven't modified the files that came out of the ZIP file.

Comment: @ThomasEyde - I wonder if the below [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/38476/#570913) may be halfway towards a way to get Explorer to run the `streams` program against the ZIP, before launching the Explorer unzipper ¿DLL?

Comment: @Charlie you can still zip up the modified files, unblock and then unzip

Comment: Is there anyway to reset this zone information once the file is unblocked? Once I unblock the file I don't see anything in file properties with the help of which I can undo this action?

Comment: If the .zip is marked as Read-Only, clicking the "Unblock" button WILL NOT WORK! To fix it: Uncheck the "Read Only" attribute, Unblock it, then re-check the "Read Only" attribute box again.

Comment: `and hunting down the zip file in the download folder or even worse, the temp folder, is very tedious` ; more tedious than unblocking the extracted files one by one? I think that's the issue.

Answer (score 111):

PowerShell, available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell), has an `Unblock-File` cmdlet that will do this task for you.  To unblock all of the files in a directory, you'd issue the following command.

`dir c:\mydir -Recurse | Unblock-File`

[Unblock-File doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file)

Comment: No longer just Beta, this is released and works quite well.

Comment: Excellent! I extracted a big zip and forgot to unblock it first, then deleted the zip to save space. This saved me downloading it again or a load of manual work :)

Comment: This worked for me but didn't provide any feedback at the cmd line. I also tweaked it slightly, if you're already in the folder then you can just do `dir -Recurse | Unblock-File`

Comment: +1 for not needing to unzip again.. made change to some files already

Comment: Works like a champ. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Unreliable for me on Windows 7 SP1 x64. Works for some directories, but not for others and I can't figure out why. No error, the data stream just remains sometimes.

Comment: Perfect. This should be the accepted answer. Unblocking the zip is fine and dandy if you remember it, but this method for doing it for a bunch of files all at once is great.

Answer (score 66):

It's quite simple, NTFS attached a data stream (that IDs "unsafe files") to the file when it is just downloaded from the Internet.

Do recursively remove this stream for all files, follow these steps :

1. Download the [Streams CLI executable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) from Microsoft
2. Put the streams.exe executable in your Windows directory (or anywhere that the system can find it)
3. Run this line in the command line :

> streams -s -d *directory*

It will then remove all of the data streams from all files recursively in the directory - you have now successfully unblocked all files.

Comment: Might be dangerous. Windows also uses streams for other purposes.

Comment: Very rare - data streams are hardly used for anything since it's an undocumented feature. It will be safe if as schnapple has said - he just wants to unblock files in a certain directory that are known to be documents received over the internet. At no point in time am I recommending him to do _streams -s -d C:\_ :)

Comment: just checked (since Streams is an undocumented feature it's hard to verify though) with some people, and they believe that once a document is transferred over the Internet or go through anything other than NTFS, it loses all stream data. As a result, when you first download something from the Internet, the only data stream you will have is that "Unsafe File" data stream.

Comment: Why do you think they're not documented? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: While this will work, just to say that Office 2007 documents use streams and that file properties are stored as streams. I suggest using "streams -d" carefully.

Comment: Don't blindly delete all alternate data streams, unless you have backup copies of those NTFS encrypted files.

Comment: This method didn't work for me anyway - it just said that it couldn't find any files with streams (even though I had the option to "Unblock" several files in their Properties screen and AlternateStreamView saw the streams).

Comment: Worked a charm for me.

Comment: @caliban: That's not entirely right. WinRAR offers the ability to save file streams when archiving and this preserves the data streams for archived files. You only lose them when you extract .RAR files onto a file system that doesn't support file streams.

Comment: It's not NTFS that attaches the source zone. It's the browser or Explorer when downloading/copying a file. The file system couldn't care less.

Comment: mine says "No files with streams found." and the problem persists

Comment: @AlexEssilfie + harrymc + Ian Boyd - Assuming you are not in the situation of [Thomas Eyde](http://superuser.com/users/27532) outlined in his [comment in another answer](http://superuser.com/questions/38476/#comment192087_38489), and that you only run any stream removing method on the immediate files downloaded from the internet via IE (something I think caliban should make cleaer in this answer)... not the result of uncompressing that/those immediate files, can't see how you won't just remove the "_:Zone.Identifier:$DATA_" streams set by IE, which is the requirement of this question.

Comment: If you do this programmatically, add the registry key that accepts the eula, then the User isn't prompted: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sysinternals\Streams]
"EulaAccepted"=dword:00000001

Comment: I had some files in my Windows 8.1 OneDrive folder and was sceptical of this approach.  Running streams.exe shows a LOT of other alternate data streams for such files.  The Powershell answer below is ideal as it leaves the other alternate data streams, such as those wanted by the OneDrive sync client, alone.

Answer (score 32):

[**AlternateStreamView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html) can list all alternate NTFS streams for files in a directory (and sub-directories if desired).

Delete all streams marked "*:Zone.Identifier:$DATA*" for the selected files to get rid of the security blocks.

[image]

Comment: There's another tool for this exact purpose - [ZoneIDTrimmer](http://www.gasanov.net/ZoneIDTrimmer.asp)

Comment: @ZoneIDTrimmer - Not sure I understand. What other tool?

Comment: ZoneIDTrimmer is the name of the tool, not the alias of the person.

Answer (score 14):

A very easy workaround for this kinda ties into the first answer, say if you have around 1000 files that are all blocked just take all the files, and put them in a new folder on your desktop (or whatever folder directory you're working in them right click said folder and then click Send To and then out of the options Click Compressed (zipped) Folder, then after that delete your original files and extract the .ZIP folder and Viola!!! all your files are unblocked :D, worked for me on XP Pro SP3, so kinda assuming it will work on vista as well

Comment: By far the least amount of work. Nice!

Comment: Still working well 10 years later on Windows 10. The nice thing about it is that it does not assume the files originated from a ZIP file.

Answer (score 11):

To disable blocking when files are downloaded, open the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments\SaveZoneInformation
```

Change SaveZoneInformation to 1.

**NOTE:**

- 0 = Not Configured
- 1 = Enabled
- 2 = Disabled

Comment: I don't have that option on windows 7 and article only mentions XP. Still, looks interesting.

Comment: Can you add the key to enable / disable? Just because you don't have a User Policy key only means that it hasn't been set up that way; you can still use it.

Comment: @user61000 - Am I right in my suspicion this only alters IE's behaviour, and not (as I found out is now done with the latest release of) Firefox (or other) browsers?

Comment: Requires admin rights :(

Comment: Just set this via the appropriate group policy (which I then confirmed set this registry key).  Thanks :)

Comment: This works in Windows 7 and 8 as well (and likely 10). Updated link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/883260. This also affects Chrome and I think Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

As another poster said the insecure file flag is stored in an NTFS data stream. What this means is there's a very easy way to remove this data stream, just move the file to a drive that doesn't support NTFS data streams.

Assuming that your problem is more related to the number of files, rather than the size of them, then the easiest way to do it might be to move *(not copy)* the files to a FAT formatted drive, then move them back to the NTFS drive (almost every USB stick is formatted FAT32 so will do nicely), and then move those files back to where you want them.

I've done this before when I've wanted to strip the blocked flag from a whole directory of downloaded files and it did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

- Download the [Sysinternals Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) utility.
- Unzip and copy streams.exe to \Windows\System32.
- Create a new text file and rename it to something like "unblocker.reg".
- Copy the below registry script in it:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\unblockfile]
  @="Unblock file"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\unblockfile\command]
  @="cmd /c streams -d \"%1\""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\unblockallthefiles]
  @="Unblock the files inside"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\unblockallthefiles\command]
  @="cmd /c streams.exe -d -s \"%1\""
  ```
- Save the file.
- Double-click the saved file to merge it into the registry.

After this, whenever you right-click a file, you can select "Unblock file" in the context menu or you can right-click a folder and select "Unblock files in here".

[source](http://obinshah.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/mass-unblock-files-remove-this-file-came-from-another-computer-warnings/)

Comment: +1 Great idea to make this process less time intensive.

Comment: It worked for me, after I added the path to streams.exe in the 8.3 format: `@="cmd /c C:\PROGRA~2\Sysinternals\streams.exe -d -s \"%1\""`

Comment: I know this is an old thread but thanks. There are multiple versions of the same reg script on the internet and most of them don't work. I can add that this worked for me on Windows 7 professional 64bit.

Answer (score 5):

AlternateStreamView is great. Another method though is to archive the files to .RAR, 7z or .ZIP . Delete the originals and then re-extract the files.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the way I unblocked the files was:

- I added all the blocked files to a RAR archive (I used WinRAR)
- I removed the original files
- I extracted all the files from the archive

All the files are now unblocked.

For me it was some MSDN Magazine issues that were in .chm format, but I do not think the file type matters.

Answer (score 1):

[ZoneIDTrimmer](http://www.gasanov.net/ZoneIDTrimmer.asp) looks like the most user-friendly tool available for this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a batch method (without using powershell) and after reading this post I came up with this simple solution

```
echo. > .\filename.zip:Zone.Identifier
```

this will not remove the `Zone.Identifier` data stream but clear it's content which seems to work fine.

Another solution (which will clear all data streams and use a temporary file is this)

```
type filename.zip > filename.zip.tmp
move /y filename.zip.tmp filename.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a usb external Hard Drive that works great for removing the blocks... I made a small partition and formatted it in FAT32..when I want to remove the block from something I simply move it to that drive and then move it back :-)

Comment: This is certainly a good approach, but it has already been mentioned in [GAThrawn's answer](http://superuser.com/a/38519).

Comment: Possibly the least risky/step intensive out of the workaround answers provided.

Answer (score -4):

Yes.  At a command prompt, `takeown /f <name of file>`.

In your case, `takeown /f *.* /r` to recurse into all sub-directories and unblock `*.*`.  Play with the pattern if necessary.

`takeown /?` for more usage instructions.

Comment: How shall that help?

Answer (score -5):

There is another easy way. Just select the file or the folder, right click it and select *Properties⇨Security⇨Edit*, then click on *Full Control*.

After that you should just click `[Save]` and exit.

Comment: This is not the place where Windows stores the information that the file comes from another computer.

Comment: Agree [Werner Henze](http://superuser.com/users/220983). Pity, though - like shreyas 's effort with the unicode arrows.