# Can I stop windows from "Blocking" zip files

Tags: windows-7, security, zip

When downloading a zip file from the internet, Windows "blocks" it. By that I mean I have to right click>Properties>and click unblock.

Is there a way to stop windows from doing this?

Comment: Related: [“This file came from another computer…” - how can I unblock all the files in a folder without having to unblock them individually?](http://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a)

Comment: You do know that Windows is doing the correct thing by blocking, right? After years of being derided as insecure, they are making great strides to being one of the leading companies in this area.

Comment: I never it said it was the wrong thing. I know what I am doing around computers, and I feel like it disrupts my flow more than it protects me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

You do not say if you are using a Pro or home version.

If you you have a Pro version, open gpedit.msc (this is not available in home version, but is easier to use) and go to:

> User Configuration>Administrative
>   Templates>Windows
>   Components>Attachment Manager

and enable the policy called

> Do not preserve zone information in
>   file attachments

Then run gpupdate /force from a command prompt.

If you have a home version of the OS, go to this registry key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments

and edit the value for key

> SaveZoneInformation to 2

You may have to create these keys, and if you want, you can also create them system-wide here:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachment‌s

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260

Comment: i'm on Win 7 ultimate. I tried both ways of doing it, rebooted, and it still makes me unblock zip files.

Comment: I have been doing this for a long time. I have been able to duplicate your lack of success. What browser are you using? Something has either changed there, or in Win 7.

Comment: Are you on a domain, or stand-alone? Also, even though the unblock button is there, what can't you do otherwise? I am able to unzip them with no problems.

Comment: not on a domain. Yes, you can still unzip fine, but the content remains "protected", and it causes annoying warnings when opening certain files (.exe, .csproj, etc..)

Comment: Oh, and I use IE and Chrome

Comment: @Joe I am actually (and have been for a few hours now) loading up a clean install of Windows 7...SP1 configuring now. I will still look at it in the morning...ok, later in the morning, as it is 1:17 am here.