# Getting error everytime when I open existing Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

Microsoft Word 2010

When I try to open existing word document, I am getting following error:

[image]

To open this document, I then have to click on Properties and click on "Unlock" button. Once I do that, it opens the file.

[image]

But this I have to do for all files. I want a solution which removes this error completely.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you try to open them? That block is (usually) caused by downloading the file from the internet. Using another Browser than IE/Edge might be able to prevent it. Alternatively you could also use a script to mass remove the flag or there might be options within Word.

Comment: If your Word files are in same directory & you want to unlock all of them, you can utilize Powershell & execute this command: `dir [path_to_directory] -Recurse | Unblock-File`, or consider read this post: https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will need to change this setting in **Group Policy Editor**
2. Click on **Start Menu** and type `gpedit.msc` and hit Enter
3. Go to **User Configuration** > **Administrative Templates** > **Attachment Manager**
4. In the window pane on the right, find **Do not preserve zone information in file attachments** and double click it
5. Select the **Enabled** radio button and then hit OK to exit out of that window
6. Reboot your computer or log off Windows and log back in for changes to take effect

Edit: If you have **Windows 7 Home Premium**, you do not have the option to open `gpedit.msc` and will need to make changes to the registry. Do the following:

1. Click the **Start Menu** and type `regedit` and hit Enter
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Policies > Attachments
3. With Attachments selected look in the right window pane for a DWORD Value called **SaveZoneInformation**, double-click it and enter a value of **1** (if the Attachments key does not exist, and there's a good chance it won't, go to the next step).

   3a. If you do not see the **Attachments** key in **Policies**, do the following: right-click on **Policies** and select **New** and then select **Key**. Name this key **Attachments**. Now right-click on **Attachments** and select **New** and then select **DWORD (32-bit) Value**. Name this value **SaveZoneInformation**. Now double-click **SaveZoneInformation** and set its value to **1**.
4. Now reboot your PC or log off Windows and log back in for the change to take effect.

^^***The above setting change will only affect any new files added to your PC going forward.***

***If you want to remove this attribute for the files already on your PC, I'd suggest the following:***

1. Move all the files you would like to remove this attribute from into one folder location. Doesn't matter where.
2. Open **Microsoft Word**
3. Go to **File** > **Options** > **Trust Center**
4. Click on **Trust Center Settings**
5. Click on **Trusted Locations**
6. Click on **Add new location**
7. Now select the folder where you had moved all your files into
8. Click on OK twice to close out both windows and you're done

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am on Windows 7 Home Basic. So Group Policy Editor is not there on my windows. What options do I have?

Comment: You can add the necessary registry key/value manually and that should work. Give me a few and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @meetpd See my Q&A [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: I have similar problem in excel. Can you please help:https://superuser.com/questions/1230778/getting-error-everytime-i-open-the-excel-file