# Getting error everytime I open the Excel File

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

Microsoft Excel 2010

When I try to open existing Excel document, I am getting following error:

[image]

I get this error when there is no Excel program/sheet opened. 
If there is, then the excel opens fine without any errors.

I want a solution which removes this error completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in Excel 2010

1. Click on the **File** tab at the top
2. Choose **Options**
3. Choose **Advanced**
4. Go to the **General** tab
5. Scroll down until you see an option called **Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)**. Currently this box is check. You want to **uncheck** it.
6. Click OK to get out of that menu and you're done. You will be able to open your Excel file now.

Comment: Hi, this checkbox is already unchecked at my end. What else can be done?

Comment: They are already unchecked. :-( What else?