# How to get rid of security warning when running batch script on network drive

Tags: windows-vista, security-warning

I have seen the following question, but this is different: [Get rid of Vista security warning](https://superuser.com/questions/23613/get-rid-of-vista-security-warning)

I wanted to make a convenience .bat script for fast cleanup (deleting several files in current directory). If i make such a .bat script in my home folder on my local computer, I can run it freely without security warnings.

However, when I copy it to H: (which resides on some central server, not my computer), I will suddenly start to get security warnings (of the type "**Open File - Security Warning**"). How can I get rid of this?

Notice that **this is a .bat script**. When you rightclick and choose properties on an .exe file, you will get the option to "unblock" the application. For .bat scripts, I do not seem to get that option though.

**EDIT:** Preferrably i would like a solution which does not require administrator permissions, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding the network server to your trusted sites in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I added the ip adress and the hostname off the network server in IE trusted sites. For the ip adress i tried adding both `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. Neither of those additions seeemed to fix the problem though. Do the setttings for internet explorer also apply to the normal file explorer? Or is there a specific place where i can add trusted sites to the file explorer?

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the Trusted Site security settings allow programs to run **without prompting**.  By default, it still prompts.And yes, these settings also apply to Explorer.

Comment: you add the server using the normal UNC style \\servername @surfasb good point, yes.

Comment: @badly: You can add that to your answer for future readers:

Comment: I tried adding the \\servername to trusted sites, as well as going into `Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted Sites -> Custom Settings` and, under `Miscellaneous` changing "Launching applications and unsafe files" from Prompt to Enable. Unfortunately, i still get the same warning when trying to run the batch script.

Comment: Try adding the full UNC path where the batch file resides instead of just the server name, it's working on my side.

Answer (score 4):

adding *.bat files to the low risk file types solves this. Explanation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883260), or in short:

- run *gpedit.msc*
- navigate to `User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Attachment Manager`
- double click `Inclusion list for low file types`
- click `Enabled` and add `*.bat` to the list
- click `Apply`, this takes effect immedeately

Comment: I was primarily looking for a way to disable the security warning for one particular file, as opposed to the security warning for all files of a certain file type. Despite this, I attempted to use your solution. However, unfortunately this does not work under my particular circumstances, as I do not have admin rights on my machine (and such rights are apparently needed to run gpedit.msc).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and used the solution that stijn provided. However, as of this morning, the warning returned. I checked, and the Group Policy was still in place, so I'm wondering if perhaps the new Windows Update changed something? Regardless, the solution I had to use was to create a shortcut to the .cmd files, and then in Properties > Advanced I selected "Run as Administrator". Not the most eloquent solution, but for my purposes, it works. I'd really like to know why this stopped working, and what I could do to make it work again, though.